# Can we pass parameters from XML file to @beforesuite method?

Tags: xml, selenium-webdriver, parameter-passing, testng, testng-dataprovider

Can we pass parameters from XML file to @beforesuite method?

TestNG.xml file

```
<suite name="Suite" verbose="1"> 
 <test name="Selenium_TestFF">
 <parameter name="Browser" value="Firefox"/>
   <classes>
      <class name="testcases.TestSuiteOne"/>
    </classes>
  </test>
  <test name="Selenium_TestC">
    <parameter name="Browser" value="Chrome"/>
    <classes>
      <class name="testcases.TestSuiteOne"/>
    </classes>
  </test>
  <test name="Selenium_TestIE">
    <parameter name="Browser" value="InternerExplorer"/>
    <classes>
      <class name="testcases.TestSuiteOne"/>
    </classes>
  </test>
</suite>
```

@BeforeSuite method with receives parameter of 'Browser' to be invoked

```
@Parameters({"Browser"})
@BeforeSuite
public void Setup(String Browser){
    System.out.println(Browser);
    driver = getDriver(Browser);    
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`@BeforeSuite` won't be able to see parameters from `<test>` context.
But it should work if you configure `<parameter>` in `<suite>` (which won't fit your needs).

To do what you expect, just replace `@BeforeSuite` by `@BeforeTest`. It will open a new different browser once by `<test>`.

Comment: Yes Julien, you are correct . I just did that and it worked fine Thanks.